# Which colors are these? (minted package)

Tags: color, minted

I am using code Highlighting for Python 3.7 with the `minted` package. I am using the tango color scheme (you can see all the color schemes `minted` uses in [this page](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Code_Highlighting_with_minted)).

I want to know the hex/rgb/cymk color code of the colors in this scheme (I want to use the same colors for other things in my document) but I cannot find them anywhere. Does anyone know these codes or/and where I can find them?

Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The colours can be found in the `pygments` source on GitHub: [tango.py](https://github.com/pygments/pygments/blob/master/pygments/styles/tango.py) and are based on the Tango colour scheme described here: [Tango Icon Theme Guidelines](http://tango.freedesktop.org/Tango_Icon_Theme_Guidelines).

[image: Tango colours]

Comment: Do you happen to know which of these are the ones chosen for the code in minted?

Comment: You can look in the `tango.py` code I linked to.

Comment: Ah you are right, thank you very much.

Comment: ah I love the efficiency and altruism on this site. sometimes it's "here's bread, eat.", but most of the time it's "your bread is bad (or not as tasty as it could be). here's a recipe for better bread. try that instead." I love it.